# Expected problems and limitations of implementing Kafka Producer in Azure Function

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, azure-functions

I have a rather high-level, architectural question which might not have a 100% clear answer. We're currently thinking about implementing a Kafka Producer within Azure Functions, as opposed to having a dedicated Producer client running in some container. The Azure Function would be invoked by some REST API call which includes the payload. The alternative solution would require something similar, the Producer application would have some custom API endpoint exposed via some Java-based framework to take data in that are then passed to Kafka via Producer API - a constantly running Java application on some container (and if necessary, redundant for parallelism).

My gut feeling tells me this approach with Azure Functions might not be a good practice, because as far as I'm aware the Producer concept in Kafka is more something "continuous" rather than something instantiated "per record" and not as short-lived as an Azure Function, which may be instantiated thousands of times in a short period of time. This approach seems unintuitive to me, as we would invoke a whole Producer lifecycle for each incoming record, generating a lot of additional network traffic to our Kafka cluster and potentially result in message ordering being arbitrary (for some use cases negligible), disregarding the fact that it's probably a quite expensive solution.

But I could also be completely mistaken, maybe it is good/best practice and there are no significant downsides regarding the concerns I mentioned. Technically, the Azure Functions approach should be scalable way easier and depending on the load, it could actually be cheaper to invoke X Azure Functions instead of having a 24/7 running producer, but that is highly dependent on the use case. Also operations in the "custom Producer" case are something that need to be taken into account, serverless does not require this kind of considerations regarding operations/deployment/maintenance.

Any thoughts or experiences on this?

Answer (score 1):

No, producers aren't necessarily continuous. If you've used `kafka-console-producer`, then you'd know this. Lambda/Function methods are no different.

Plus, Java is not necessary. Save yourself some costs/speed and don't trigger a JVM startup within a serverless function. Or, if you do, then compile a native binary using GraalVM (Quarkus or Spring Native can help with this)

Comment: What would you recommend instead of a Java producer? I planned to stay as native as possible, hence Java/Scala, but I can see that Confluent also offers clients for Python, Go, C/C++ and .NET by now, additional to a multitude of other clients offered by the open-source community. Now I'm at a weird spot of deciding, I'm not that familiar with every single of those languages and their performance (or effort of development respectively) to compare at one glance. I've worked with Go and I know it's fast, but Azure does only offer a generic runtime stack for Go, does this mitigate its advantage?

Comment: Since we're running on Confluent Cloud, I'll exclude non-Confluent options, but still there is a multitude of options that are hard to evaluate/compare: **Java with native binary** (as mentioned by you), **Java with Kafka bindings** (AzFunction-specific solution for Kafka integration, not sure how that compares to previous option performance-wise? will this start up a JVM?), **Go** (no dedicated runtime for AzFunction, yet feasible), **C#** (this will spin up a .NET VM though, comparable to JVM start-up?). Is there a right answer or does it all boil down to preference and the overall stack?

Comment: A cold start problem will certainly exist with lambda functions. Regrading language, Azure can run any container using services other than Lambda functions. You don't necessarily need a specific runtime environment stack to be supported. For example, forward an HTTP request to some service running AKS. The Java API introduces client features quickest, but for basic producing, then use what you're comfortable with, or benchmark a few different options